# How shuffling is done in MapReduce?

Tags: mapreduce

[image]

It seems pretty straightforward, just one thing I don't quite understand is how shuffling is done? How can you create a basket for each word here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`map`'s output Key, Value pairs (let's call them `K,V`) are partitioned based on a hash of the key.

All of the `K,V` pairs with the same `hash(K)` are sent to the same reducer. The `K,V` pairs in each reducer are sorted by key and grouped by key.

`reduce` then processes each key and all of its associated values in turn.

N.B. In Hadoop (and possibly other M/R implementations), the partition, sorting and grouping functions can be user-defined.